# Post value using ajax to function autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have here a dropdown select and autocomplete function. What I need to do is to pass the selected value of dropdown to autocomplete.php to use in my query. Textbox value should depending on value from dropdown. If selected value is supplies, all supplies only value in textbox (like pencil or ballpen).

I used this Ajax in Dynamic Dropdown. How I can use this to pass the value in autocomplete.php?

**Note:** this Ajax was not connected in my autocomplete function. How I can use this ajax to pass the value to my autocomplete.php query.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#main').change(function(){
$.ajax({
url : 'getajax.php',
data :{mainlist_id : $(this).val()},
dataType:'html',
type:'POST',
success:function(data){
$('#sub').html(data);
}
});
});
</script>
```

**Ajax.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#tag").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
        selectFirst: true
    });
});
</script>

Drop1
 <?php
    $combo = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM category GROUP BY cat_code ORDER BY id");
    $option = '';
     while($row = $combo->fetch_assoc())
        {
        $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['cat_code'].'">'.$row['category'].'</option>';
        }
    ?>

<select id="main" name="main">
<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose</option>
<?php echo $option; ?>
</select>
Auto Complete <input id="tag" type="text">
```

**Autocomplete.php**

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "2015") or die("Database Error");
    $auto = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET["q"]);
    $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM code WHERE item LIKE '%$auto%' GROUP BY id ORDER BY item" ); 

    if($sql)
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {
            echo $row['item']."\n";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: the ajax url should be "Autocomplete.php" no "getajax.php"

Comment: @chen I add that only to show I used ajax. But I already tried your suggestion but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

`$('#sub').html(data);` should be `$('#tag').html(data);`

Comment: I already tried that. But when I try to type in textbox autocomplete doesn't work

Comment: the textbox that you're trying to autocomplete from the dropdown?

Comment: the ajax above was not connected in my autocomplete function. What I need to do is pass the dropdown value so I can used that in my query. And inlucde this in my query for example. $main = $_POST["mainlist_id"]; and add this in my select query "cat_code='$main' "

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined `#sub` element in your `html` code, when placing this

```
$('#sub').html(data);
```

After that your name of the page must be same, while your using `getajax.php`, and its not you have defined us

Comment: that was an example. It's not connected in my autocomplete function. I just posted that to ask if how I can use that to pass the value on autocomplete.php query